# Different value for Where clause slows down query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query which pulls data from a view, which is already very large (>10.000.000 rows). I know, stupid to do that, but nut my decision.

The query is already very slow. But if i change the value of Where criteria the query runs very long or seems like it never will finish. Has anyone an explanation for this problem? For me it seems like that the sql server has optimized the query for this criteria parameter and the other ones need forever.

Comment: Can you give us a sample of the data in the view, your query code (with the unchanged where clause), and your code (with the changed where clause). It's hard to help you if we don't know the details of your question.

Comment: Sounds to me like either poor indexing or bad parameter sniffing. Without any details though it is a crap shoot what the actual problem is.

Comment: Depending on your hardware (bare metal or virtualized), a 10M row view shouldn't be slow. We have an index that combines three tables and has about 2 billion rows. With proper indexing, your queries shouldn't be slow.

Comment: Thx. Patrick for the input, was always thinking that, at this number of rows, views are already problematic. Remaining problem is that there are no indexes on views, yet

Answer (score 4):

Yup, this is quite normal. Different queries have different optimal plans, and if you're passing the arguments correctly, the same execution plan is used for all the different arguments.

Apart from a database redesign, you could just try using `option(recompile)`. Do note that this has its own issues - like increased memory consumption, latency...

Try do find out *why* the problem is there - looking at the actual execution plans for the two queries is usually a good idea.